# How to set the axis labels on Q3DSurface?

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d, qt5, qwidget

I tried to set axis labels on `Q3DSurface` by doing the following:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <Q3DSurface>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    Q3DSurface *graph = new Q3DSurface;
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    setCentralWidget(widget);
    graph->axisX()->setLabels(QStringList{"a", "b", "c"});
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```

But the labels are not showing, any hint on how to show them?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting this property for QValue3DAxis does nothing, as it generates labels automatically.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstract3daxis.html#labels-prop

Answer (score 0):

I think you wants to set axis titles, not labels. The titles hidden by default

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <Q3DSurface>

using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    Q3DSurface *graph = new Q3DSurface;
    QWidget *widget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
    setCentralWidget(widget);

    m_graph->axisX()->setTitle(QStringLiteral("a"));
    m_graph->axisY()->setTitle(QStringLiteral("b"));
    m_graph->axisZ()->setTitle(QStringLiteral("c"));

    m_graph->axisX()->setTitleVisible(true);
    m_graph->axisY()->setTitleVisible(true);
    m_graph->axisZ()->setTitleVisible(true);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {}
```